# Why does my C# program pause so often when running from the Windows 7 command line?

Tags: c#, windows-7, command-line

I've had this problem with several different C# apps. These are all utility programs I've written to make my life as a sysadmin easier. Things like migrating data between database servers.

They print their current step to the console (old versions through System.Console.WriteLine(), newer ones through log4net's ConsoleAppender), so I always run them from a command prompt. When doing so, they often seem to pause at random intervals until I hit enter a few times. I notice they're paused because a step that usually takes a second or two has been on the screen for a long time. After hitting enter, things start processing normally again for a while.

Why is this? How can I fix it?

Comment: I suspect this may be caused by selecting content in the console window?  You can tell this state by looking at the title of the console window and see if it begins with the word "Select".

When a selection starts in the console window it blocks all further output from any program until the selection mode has been exited.  This is done by pressing [Enter] which copies the content to the clipboard.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you select text on the command window screen using the mouse, it often pauses execution of the program that is running.  You might be accidentally creating a text selection when clicking on the window with the mouse.

Comment: I think you're right. Just clicking in the window causes a one-character select and I can reproduce this behavior by doing so. Thanks!

Comment: Does anyone know if this behavior changes with different versions of Windows?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest assumption - an application goes to the branch with the call `Console.ReadLine()`.
It is not enough information to make any other assumption.
Eventually, try to initiate Break-command in the debugger during the program hanging, etc.